# Using the Phylo library is there a way to create a distance matrix from a tree after you have already converted it from a dm to a tree?

Tags: python, tree, phylogeny

Essentially I created a distance matrix and created a tree using 2 different methods, I am now trying to calculate the dm of each method and compare it to the starting dm.

I tried looking through the documentation, and could not find anything specifically doing what I want to do. I thought about using a distance calculator but it keeps asking me to align and I keep getting an error about that alignment. When I try to align it says something about an empty handle so I am a bit stuck now.